# How to refer the wp_users table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to add some tables to my wordpress database and refer to the `wp_users` table with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Now after trying around a little i keep getting the following output:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2018-04-08 22:27:20 31fc Error in foreign key constraint of table `wordpress`.`wp_foo`:
Create  table `wordpress`.`wp_foo` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `wordpress`.`wp_users` not found in the data dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES wp_users(id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)'.
------------
```

The statement I executed:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_foo (
    user_id bigint(20) unsigned,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

How can I refer that `wp_users.ID` attribute?

Edit:

Output after update of statement (see comments below):

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2018-04-08 23:16:21 3470 Error in foreign key constraint of table `wordpress`.`wp_foo`:
Create  table `wordpress`.`wp_foo` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `wordpress`.`wp_users` not found in the data dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)'.
------------
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your `id` field, primary key and foreign key are all named the same way. To prevent confusion you'll want to use different names (eg. `... user_id bigint(20) unsigned, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id) ...`)

Comment: Jeah, I am going to do it that way, I just wanted to test a small example to see what does not work out. Still thanks for your answer.

Comment: Actually, as a test I ran this query on PHPMyAdmin with the changes I mentioned on my previous comment and the table was created without issues. Give what I said a go and check again.

Comment: Can you copy in what you inserted? I updated the code in my question and ran it on my wordpress-database and I got the output below the statement.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE wp_foo ( user_id bigint(20) unsigned, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id), PRIMARY KEY (user_id) )` results in `[green checkmark] MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0833 seconds.)` on PHPMyAdmin (and the table got created successfully).

Comment: It works for me if I uncheck the Foreign_Key_Check in phpmyadmin. But that can't be the solution right? Did you also uncheck it?

Comment: If you do a 'use information_schema;select * from innodb_sys_tables;' does it have a row for 'wordpress/wp_users'?

Comment: @Rüdiger nope, I left it enabled. Didn't touch it (I avoid doing that unless there's a good reason... or if I'm in a hurry.)

Comment: @magenta No there is no wordpress/wp_users

Comment: Then I don't think the table wordpress.wp_users exits. Are you sure you have the right table name? Is there any row like 'wordpress/..._users'?

Comment: I do have a wp_users in the wordpress database... what could've happened there?

Comment: But there are only the self-made tables in that table, not the default wordpress tables. So it looks like that would be alright

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? From version 5.6 the default database engine is InnoDB and AFAIK all tables created with this database engine has an entry in innodb_sys_tables.Older versions of MySQL uses the MyISAM database engine - I don't know where it stores its table information.

Comment: Can you run "select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'wp_users';". If there is any output what is the value of the column 'ENGINE'?